# context.getTheme().resolveAttribute() returns incorrect color value on Android 12 when UIMode changes

Tags: android, android-12, android-dark-theme

To avoid UI recreate I add these code to My Project.

AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
...
<activity
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
...
```

Activity

```java
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(@NonNull Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if(isNightMode != ExampleUtil.isNightMode()){
        isNightMode = !isNightMode;
            onUIModeChanges();
            setupTheme();
    }
}
@Override
public void onUIModeChanges() {
    int colorBgd = ExampleUtil.getColorInt(this, android.R.attr.colorBackground);
    int colorScrim = ExampleUtil.getColorInt(this, R.attr.scrimBackground);
    int colorPrimary = ExampleUtil.getColorInt(this, R.attr.colorPrimary);
    int colorOnPrimary = ExampleUtil.getColorInt(this, R.attr.colorOnPrimary);
    int colorSurface = ExampleUtil.getColorInt(this, R.attr.colorSurface);
    int colorOnSurface = ExampleUtil.getColorInt(this, R.attr.colorOnSurface);
    // using these color above to update UI widgets.
}
```

ExampleUtil.java

```java
public static boolean isNightMode() {
    return isNightMode(Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration());
}

public static boolean isNightMode(Configuration configuration) {
    return (configuration.uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK) == Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES;
}
public static int getColorInt(Context context, @AttrRes int resId) {
    TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
    context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(resId, tv, true);
    if (tv.type == TypedValue.TYPE_STRING) return ContextCompat.getColor(context, tv.resourceId);
    return tv.data;
}
```

> Firstly I'm pretty sure that the `ExampleUtil.isNightMode()` returns the correct value.

Before Android 12, it works fine(on all the devices I have)

But when it comes to Android 12, it only effective once(Tested on Apple M1 Android Emulator and my Google Pixel 3)
[image: Effect Preview]

I debugged the code then I found that starting from the second UIMode change, the function `ExampleUtil.getColorInt()` always returns the same result.

That's pretty odd.